# User under windows server AD access Linux server using kerberos

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, kerberos

I installed AD on windows 2008 r2 sp1 server . And had configured all things follow the issue

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995329.aspx

http://www.safesquid.com/content-filtering/integrating-linux-host-windows-ad-kerberos-sso-authentication
.

Now I used a windows client (windows 7 sp1 , and IE 10)  which under the AD , to access a website which setup on Linux system (nginx http server) , but not success.

the client can not get a kerberos ticket , and always get a 403 response .

What shoud I do ?

Comment: Ha nginx been set up to use LDAP authentication against your AD?

Comment: also explain your troubleshooting steps performed

Comment: what about apache? Does apache can do LDAP?

Comment: The appropriate configuration would be helpful. Those links may go down in the future.